# Svelte SPA button click does not back to normal style state

Tags: javascript, css, single-page-application, svelte, bulma

This is just SPA with javascript svelte framework.

I have buttons using bulma CSS Framework. As you can see in the preview when I click the button, and the cursor leave the button, the button style state still in click state.

how to solve this? so after click, the button back to normal style state?

I write it again in svelte

you can check in this [svelte REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/a4d59c32a455489a93ea02ac098813b9?version=3.29.4).

```
<svelte:head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Hello Bulma!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.1/css/bulma.min.css">
</svelte:head>
<script>
    let stepIndex = 0;
    let steps = [
        {
            text: 'Welcome to the 100 days project to help us better',
            buttonText: 'Next'
        },
        {
            text: 'We believe biological conditions influence psychological situations',
            buttonText: 'Next'
        },
        {
            text: 'Life begins with us thinking that we are alive',
            buttonText: 'Next'
        },
        {
            text: 'Experience a better life after 100 days commitment',
            buttonText: 'Next'
        },
        {
            text: 'Do you want have a better life',
            buttonText: 'Yes!!!'
        }
    ];
    function next(data){
        stepIndex++;
    }
</script>

<div>
    <i class="fa fa-quote-left fa-2x fa-pull-left fa-border" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <p class="is-size-4 has-text-grey has-text-weight-semibold">{steps[stepIndex].text}</p>
    <hr />
    <div class="columns is-mobile">
          <div class="column">
                <button class="button is-danger is-medium is-fullwidth is-outlined" on:click={()=>alert("Don't back, Just go forward!!!")}>
            <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></span><span>Back</span>
            </button>
            </div>
        <div class="column">
            <button class="button is-primary is-medium is-fullwidth is-outlined" on:click={()=>next()}>
                <span>{steps[stepIndex].buttonText}</span> <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't think this problem nothing to do with my code, but I try to share some in svelte. because it have same problem. wish you can help me to solve this problem.

thanks

[image: Example]

Comment: Without your code, the answer is *you fix it by fixing it*

Comment: That appearance is probably being set on both hover and focus. So long as the button has focus, it'll keep that appearance.

Comment: Hi everyone, I tried to create an example code, yes, I use Bulma CSS Framework, hope there is a solve

Comment: @Ouroborus so what I can do to solve this? hmm may is not good if I overwrite the bulma css, is there any solution? thanks

Comment: I just found this is only problem in Chrome Browser, with other browser have no problem